# Pattern matching in a file

Tags: regex, grep

> Collocation -> n A m a k a (Collocation -> Words, Words -> Word Words, Word -> n A (Word -> Chars, Chars -> Char Chars, Char -> 'n', Chars -> Char, Char -> 'A'), Words -> Word Words, Word -> m a (Word -> Chars, Chars -> Char Chars, Char -> 'm', Chars -> Char, Char -> 'a'), Words -> Word, Word -> k a (Word -> Chars, Chars -> Char Chars, Char -> 'k', Chars -> Char, Char -> 'a'))

I have  a file containing 1000s of line like this. I want to search the pattern like this "Word -> n A (" that is,

1. it should start with "Word -> "
2. After that it can contain any number of alphabets in any case
3. Ends with an opening bracket "("

Example from above line I want,

1. Word -> n A (
2. Word -> m a (
3. Word -> k a (

I have tried this grep command:
grep -no "Word -> .*(" filename

But, it returns like this:

> Word -> n A (Word -> Chars, Chars -> Char Chars, Char -> 'n', Chars -> Char, Char -> 'A'), Words -> Word Words, Word -> m a (Word -> Chars, Chars -> Char Chars, Char -> 'm', Chars -> Char, Char -> 'a'), Words -> Word, Word -> k a (

Also I want all the matching pattern in a line comes in one line in output file.

Also suggest if it can be done by any other method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -no 'Word -> [[:alpha:] ]\+(' file
1:Word -> n A (
1:Word -> m a (
1:Word -> k a (
```

The above shows the line numbers in the original file on which the regex matched.  If, instead, you want matches numbered sequentially, then:

```
$ grep -o 'Word -> [[:alpha:] ]\+(' file | cat -n
     1  Word -> n A (
     2  Word -> m a (
     3  Word -> k a (
```

The original code used `.*`.  There are two problems with that.  One is that `.` matches anything including `(`.  The second is that the regex is greedy: it matches the longest matching string.

Here, in place of `.*`, we used `[[:alpha:] ]\+`.  This matches one or more letters and spaces.  Since this only matches letters and spaces, it will not match `(` and thus the match will be the length that you want.

Note that we are using `[:alpha:]` to match letters.  Unlike older forms like `[a-zA-Z]`, `[:alpha:]` is unicode safe.

The problem with using `.*` is that it is greedy: it will match the longest possible match.  You appear to want the shortest match.